# Pandas groupby for zero values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data like this in a csv file

```
Symbol  Action  Year
  AAPL     Buy  2001
  AAPL     Buy  2001
   BAC    Sell  2002
   BAC    Sell  2002
```

I am able to read it and groupby like this

```
df.groupby(['Symbol','Year']).count()
```

I get

```
             Action
Symbol Year        
AAPL   2001       2
BAC    2002       2
```

I desire this (order does not matter)

```
             Action
Symbol Year        
AAPL   2001       2
AAPL   2002       0
BAC    2001       0
BAC    2002       2
```

I want to know if its possible to count for zero occurances

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print df.pivot_table(index='Symbol', 
                     columns='Year', 
                     values='Action',
                     fill_value=0, 
                     aggfunc='count').unstack()

Year  Symbol
2001  AAPL      2
      BAC       0
2002  AAPL      0
      BAC       2
dtype: int64
```

If you need output as `DataFrame` use [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
print df.pivot_table(index='Symbol', 
                     columns='Year', 
                     values='Action',
                     fill_value=0, 
                     aggfunc='count').unstack()
                                     .to_frame()
                                     .rename(columns={0:'Action'})

             Action
Year Symbol        
2001 AAPL         2
     BAC          0
2002 AAPL         0
     BAC          2
```

Comment: This makes a beautiful pivot table but using fill_value=0 still doesn't display the rows with a count of 0 for me. I thought fill_value was just for rows with missing data or NaNs?

Comment: Yes parameter fill_value replace NaN to 0.

Answer (score 52):

You can use this:

```
df = df.groupby(['Symbol','Year']).count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
print (df)
```

Output:

```
             Action
Symbol Year        
AAPL   2001       2
       2002       0
BAC    2001       0
       2002       2
```

Comment: This is a nice solution! Elegant and intuitive and better than using `pivot_table`, unless the latter has any advantages or specific use-cases. Do you know of any?

Comment: Does this work for only one group by object? it doesn't seem to work and it is fiving me AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'

Answer (score 6):

**Datatype category**

Maybe this feature didn't exist back when this thread was opened, however the datatype "category" can help here:

```
# create a dataframe with one combination of a,b missing
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0,1,1], "b": [0,1,0]})
df = df.astype({"a":"category", "b":"category"})
print(df)
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  1  0
```

And now, grouping by a and b

```
print(df.groupby(["a","b"]).size())
```

yields:

```
a  b
0  0    1
   1    0
1  0    1
   1    1
```

Note the 0 in the rightmost column. This behavior is also documented in the [pandas userguide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#operations) (search on page for "groupby").

Comment: I meet this situation when I don't need zero !

Comment: @Mithril if you mean that you have a categorical column and .groupby is giving you all possible combinations when you only want the observed combinations, you'll want to use groupby(..., observed=True), as documented here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#handling-of-un-observed-categorical-values

Comment: I want all combinations for categorical columns, but not for non-categorical columns. I think this gives combinations for all columns, just because one of the columns is categorical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without using pivot_table, you can try the below approach:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ df['Symbol'].unique(), df['Year'].unique()], names=['Symbol', 'Year'])
df_grouped_by = df_grouped_by.reindex(midx, fill_value=0)
```

What we are essentially doing above is creating a multi-index of all the possible values multiplying the two columns and then using that multi-index to fill zeroes into our group-by dataframe.

Comment: this sets all counts to zero for me, instead of the ones that don't appear in the data

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a dataframe that stores the count of each non-zero class in the column **counts**

```
count_df = df.groupby(['Symbol','Year']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

Step 2: Now use pivot_table to get the desired dataframe with counts for both existing and non-existing classes.

```
df_final = pd.pivot_table(count_df,
                       index=['Symbol','Year'],
                       values='counts',                            
                       fill_value = 0,
                       dropna=False,
                       aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Now the values of the counts can be extracted as a list with the command

```
list(df_final['counts'])
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are focusing on groupby or pivot table. However, as is well described in [this article](https://pbpython.com/pandas-crosstab.html) and in [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/94436/pandas-groupby-count-doesnt-count-zero-occurrences), this is a beautiful case for  pandas' [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) function:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Symbol": 2*['AAPL', 'BAC'],
    "Action": 2*['Buy', 'Sell'],
    "Year": 2*[2001,2002]
})

pd.crosstab(df["Symbol"], df["Year"]).stack()
```

yielding:

```
Symbol  Year
AAPL    2001    2
        2002    0
BAC     2001    0
        2002    2
```

Comment: What if the number of years doesn't match the number of stock symbols?