# count instances per day pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,1]],columns=['day','class'])
```

and I would like to count the instances of class 1 each day. I use groupby in this way,

```
df.groupby(['class','day'])['class'].count()

Out[51]: 
day  class
1    0        2
2    0        1
     1        1
Name: class, dtype: int64
```

but I would like to have also that in day 1 class 1 there are no instances:

```
Out[51]: 
day  class
1    0        2
     1        0
2    0        1
     1        1
Name: class, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby for zero values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003100/pandas-groupby-for-zero-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with parameter `fill_value=0` and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['day','class'])['class'].count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
print (df)
day  class
1    0        2
     1        0
2    0        1
     1        1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

With pivot_table, even if less elegant than jezrael's solution:

```
df['class1'] = df['class']
df = df.pivot_table(index='class', columns='day', values='class1',
                 fill_value=0, aggfunc='count').unstack()
```

Output:

```
day  class
1    0        2
     1        0
2    0        1
     1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. Categories ensure that when you perform a `groupby` operation, every combination is maintained.

This is a more data-oriented versus operation-oriented solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,0], [1,0], [2,0], [2,1]],
                  columns=['day', 'class'],
                  dtype='category')

df['count'] = 1
res = df.groupby(['class', 'day'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
res['count'] = res['count'].fillna(0)

#   class day  count
# 0     0   1    2.0
# 1     0   2    1.0
# 2     1   1    0.0
# 3     1   2    1.0
```