# Retain row with 0 element when using . groupby().sum()

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe containing various dates and a corresponding value for that date. I am attempting to group the data by week and sum the values for the week, for the 15th and 16th there is no data (as expected) so when I group the data and sum the resultant dataframe does not contain weeks 15 and 16.

I would like to produce a dataframe that contain rows 15 and 16 but has a value of 0 in each

Please see code as per image below

[image: Current code and output]

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.ExcessCash > 0].groupby('Date').a.count()
     .reindex(df.date.unique()).fillna(0).astype(int)
     .rename('ExcessCashResult').reset_index()
```

reference:
[How to keep Zero counts for pandas groupby count for 2 columns dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884959/how-to-keep-zero-counts-for-pandas-groupby-count-for-2-columns-dataframe)